# Create PHPExcel from array of objects

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a PersonMapper that reads from a DB and creates Person objects (PHP Slim Framework 3):

```
<?php
class PersonMapper extends Mapper {

    public function getPersons() {
        $stmt = $this->db->query("SELECT p.id, p.firstname, p.pastname FROM persons p");
        $results = [];
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $results[] = new Person($row);
        }
        return $results;
    }
}

class Person implements ArrayAccess {
    protected $id;
    protected $firstname;
    protected $lastname;

    public function __construct(array $data) {
        // no id if we're creating
        if(isset($data['id'])) { $this->id = $data['id']; }
        $this->firstname= $data['firstname'];
        $this->lastname= $data['lastname'];
    }

    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function getFirstname() { return $this->firstname; }
    public function getLastname() { return $this->lastname; }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return array_key_exists($offset, $this->asArray());
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->offsetExists($offset) ? $this->asArray()[$offset]:NULL;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        $this->asArray()[$offset] = $value; 
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        if ($this->offsetExists($offset)) {
            $_array = $this->asArray();
            unset($_array[$offset]);
        }
    }

    public function asArray() {
        return array(
            'id' => $this->id, 
            'firstname' => $this->firstname, 
            'kurzbezeichnung' => $this->lastname);
    }
}
```

I am now able to get an array of person objects:

```
$mapper = new PersonMapper($this->db);
$persons= $mapper->getPersons();
```

Now I want to put the list of persons into an excel file:

```
    $excelDoc = new PHPExcel();
    $excelDoc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $excelDoc->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($persons, null, 'A1');

    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelDoc, 'Excel2007');
    $writer->save("persons.xlsx");
```

Unfortunately, PHPExcel can't handle this kind of data structure:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Person could not be converted to
string in /path/to/src/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/
PHPExcel/Cell/DefaultValueBinder.php on line 65
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think PHP offers any way to convert an object to an array automatically. Each individual "person" is an object, so you probably need to convert each "person" to an array before adding adding the array of persons.

Comment: The `fromArray()` method works with arrays, or an array of arrays, not on an array of objects (unless those objects implement [ArrayAccess](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php))

Comment: So, my Person class should implement ArrayAccess?

Comment: If the `Person` class implemented `ArrayAccess`, then yes, you could use `fromArray()` with an array of Person objects

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect the changes I made. Person now implements the ArrayAccess interface. However, the error message is still the same. I wonder why PHP excel wants to convert Person to string. If I understand correctly, Person should be an array and only its attributes should be strings!?

Comment: Your PersonMapper uses p.pastname in the query, not p.lastname. Just a typo here or also in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try : [As per oficial documentation](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples), you need first to save the file with the object writer

Please let me know if this is what you wanted

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

require_once('PHPExcel.php');

$sheet = array(
    array(
      'a1 data',
      'b1 data',
      'c1 data',
      'd1 data',
    )
  );

  $doc = new PHPExcel();
  $doc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

  $doc->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($sheet, null, 'A1');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_name.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

  // Do your stuff here
  $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($doc, 'Excel5');

$writer->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: I am able to write a perfect excel file as long as I don't try to put custom objects into the file. I guess that I have to take care that the objects are converted to arrays (see comments to my original post).

Answer (score 0):

After implementing ArrayAccess you only need to loop over every of your persons and pass the person to fromArray as an array.

I tested with the following lines of code and it worked:

Replace this part `$excelDoc->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($persons, null, 'A1');` with this

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $excelDoc->getActiveSheet()->fromArray((array)$person, null, "A" . $i++);
}
```

This will paste ID, firstname and kurzbezeichnung in cells A, B and C for each person